# Can't open any question when logged out

Tags: bug

When I log out and try to open any question on Astronomy Stack Exchange, I get [this error](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/24642/speed-of-light-in-a-black-hole). The Meta works fine and also when I log in, everything works as expected.

[image: error]

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this while logged out (even checking [the same question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24642/speed-of-light-in-a-black-hole)). Is this still happening, and if so, can you specify what browser (and maybe OS) you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just started working again…